# Outlook Javascript API - Add in to replace regex matches with link

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin

I want to create an Outlook 2016 compatible add-in that just replaces a regex match with a hyperlink.  My main problem is I don't know how to access the message body.  Is there an example project I can look at that does this?

Here's my manifest.xml

```
        <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
          <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
          <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="OrderNumber" RegExValue="N\d{5}" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
        </Rule>
```

Here's my javascript

```
        export async function run() {
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
    "text",
    { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
    function callback(result) {
    const r = /N\d{5}/;

        var allMatches = result.value.match(r);

        if (allMatches) {
          JSON.stringify(allMatches, null, 2);
        } else {
          //allMatches = "All matches was null";
        }    
        for (var i = allMatches.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            document.getElementById("item-subject").innerHTML += "<b>Order ID's:</b> <br/>" + "<a href='https://www.test.com.au/admin/order/vieworder?id=" + allMatches[i] + "'>" + allMatches[i] + "</a><br>";
        }

       // document.getElementById("item-subject").innerHTML = "<b>Order ID's:</b> <br/>" + "<a href='https://www.test.com/admin/order/vieworder?id='" + allMatches + ">" + allMatches + "</a>";
    });
```

mostly working solution

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you, you seem to be able to access it like so:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('text', function bodyCallback(result) {
  console.log('value:', result.value)
});
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview

[image]

Comment: I am now getting the message body, thanks.  But I've been informed by the next poster  (Outlook Add-ins Team MSFT) that it's not possible to edit the message body in place, in Outlook.  Do you know of any way to do that?  I want compatibility with pretty much any version of Outlook 2016 (Win and Mac) and up, and if possible including mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

If this questions is in regards to Web Add-ins:

While you are composing a message, mountaindrew's comment is correct. There are ways to both get the body data, and set the body data using the linked questions.

While you are reading a message that you have received, it is not possible to modify the body in place. You could get the body with Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(), and open a taskpane with the contents modified in the taskpane as a workaround.

If you are trying to do this with a COM Add-in, what you are asking is possible, but I do not have the expertise. (and you should ask this question with the appropriate tags (untag web add-ins))

Comment: I actually want to modify the contents of a received message in place, just turning the order number text into a hyperlink.

Comment: Currently modifying body of received message is not supported, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.